Any Regex question to split a summary from txt file
I'm trying to extract some content from txt file (from pdf conversion).
You can notice space (or not) after label or before page_number and sometimes, there is no \n between page_number and X.Y.Z code
Here is a sample :
Summary
...
30. LOT 03 CLOS COUVERT.................... 29 
30.1. LOT 03-1 ETANCHEITE .................... 29 
30.1.1. Travaux divers.................... 29 
30.1.1.1. Boite à eau.................... 29 
30.1.1.2. Descentes d’eaux pluviales en façades .................30 
30.1.1.3. Lanterneau de désenfumage...............30 30.1.1.4. Etanchéité résine..................31 
...

The structure of the summary is :
X.Y.Z. Label ....................... Page_number

And later in the same doc we can found description associated :
30. LOT 03 CLOS COUVERT (no description here)
30.1. LOT 03-1 ETANCHEITE (no description here)
...
30.1.1.1. Boite à eau 
Composition : -Descente d\’eaux pluviales 
o en zinc naturel, épaisseur 0.80 mm 
o en tle laquée jaune sur les zones d\’enduit jaune -Moignon cylindrique du diamètre de la descente EP -Trop-plein rectangulaire positionné sur face avant etc ...
30.1.1.2. Descentes d\’eaux pluviales en façades 
Fourniture et pose de descentes d\'eaux en zinc extérieures type VM Zinc
...

My use case is to put X.Y.Z Label into a python dict as keys from the summary only and associate descriptions to this. Expected outpout looks like this :
{ '30. LOT 03 CLOS COUVERT' : '',
'30.1. LOT 03-1 ETANCHEITE' : '',
...
'30.1.1.1. Boite à eau' : 'Composition : -Descente d’eaux pluviales 
o en zinc naturel, épaisseur 0.80 mm 
o en tle laquée jaune sur les zones d\’enduit jaune -Moignon cylindrique du diamètre de la descente EP -Trop-plein rectangulaire positionné sur face avant etc ...',
'30.1.1.2. Descentes d\’eaux pluviales en façades' : 'Fourniture et pose de descentes d\'eaux en zinc extérieures type VM Zinc...'}

I tried this regex which is the best result I can get but it's not the best :
(\d+[.])(.*)?[.]*\s*\d+

My problem is about dot managing, label extraction and \n missing.
Could you please healp me ?

I've tried to fix your formatting of the input. But it's not clear what is actually part of the file -- is the line > Summary in the file or not? And does it really include the > character. Please correct the edit if I got something wrong.

There's no point in putting ? after (.*). * already allows a zero-length match, so it's inherently optional.

You keep saying that the code is X.Y.Z. But the sample data looks like W.X.Y.Z. Is it only supposed to use the first 3 numbers as the key?

None of your sample lines have Label :

Can you add the expected result to the question?

you can handle the missing \n by matching (^|\s) before the key numbers.

Ok, query edited, thanks for your feedback ! I am checking all of your propositions and I will back with the right one ;)

You might use 2 capture groups, where the first group is the key and the second group is the description.
If this is specifically about the dots that you want to omit:
\b(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)\.[^\S\n]+([\s\S]*?)\.{2,}\s*\d+\b

See a regex demo and a Python demo
Example
import pprint
import re
 
regex = r"\b(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)\.[^\S\n]+([\s\S]*?)\.{2,}\s*\d+\b"
 
s = ("> Summary\n"
            "30.1.3.1. Boite à eau................................................................................................................................................. 29 \n"
            "30.1.3.2. Descentes d’eaux pluviales en façades ....................................................................................................30 \n"
            "30.1.3.3. Lanterneau de désenfumage.....................................................................................................................30 30.1.3.4. Etanchéité résine.......................................................................................................................................31")
 
pprint.pprint(dict(re.findall(regex, s)))

Output
{'30.1.3.1': 'Boite à eau',
 '30.1.3.2': 'Descentes d’eaux pluviales en façades ',
 '30.1.3.3': 'Lanterneau de désenfumage',
 '30.1.3.4': 'Etanchéité résine'}


If you want the whole part including the dots right before the page number, then the group 2 value matches until either a new key starts after a page number OR when it is the last description with a page number followed by the end of the string.
\b(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)\.[^\S\n]+([\s\S]*?)\s*\b(?=\d+\s*$|\d+\s+\d+(?:\.\d+)*\.)

See a regex demo and a Python demo

Thanks a lot ! your regex does the job perfectly. I updated my question adding some requests ;) (about description). If you have got an idea it would be a pleasure.

Hello, I've got the same issue regarding this pattern : "12.2.1.1.1.1 Porte à 1 vantail 7 12.2.1.1.2 Blocs-portes de distribution 5 test 7 " I can't adapt the regex "\b(\d+(?:.\d+)).[^\S\n]+([\s\S]?).{2,}\s*\d+\b" without dot betwwen label and page number. Do you have an idea ? Thanks

IIUC, you can use re.findall and (\d+(?:\.\d+)*\.) (.*?)\.* ?(\d+):
import re

txt = '''Summary
30.1.3.1. Boite à eau................................................................................................................................................. 29 
30.1.3.2. Descentes d’eaux pluviales en façades ....................................................................................................30 
30.1.3.3. Lanterneau de désenfumage.....................................................................................................................30 30.1.3.4. Etanchéité résine.......................................................................................................................................31 '''

out = re.findall(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)*\.) (.*?)\.* ?(\d+)', txt)

out2 = {k: t for k, *t in out}

Output:
# out
[('30.1.3.1.', 'Boite à eau', '29'),
 ('30.1.3.2.', 'Descentes d’eaux pluviales en façades ', '30'),
 ('30.1.3.3.', 'Lanterneau de désenfumage', '30'),
 ('30.1.3.4.', 'Etanchéité résine', '31')]

# out2
{'30.1.3.1.': ['Boite à eau', '29'],
 '30.1.3.2.': ['Descentes d’eaux pluviales en façades ', '30'],
 '30.1.3.3.': ['Lanterneau de désenfumage', '30'],
 '30.1.3.4.': ['Etanchéité résine', '31']}

regex demo
If you just want the labels as keys and descriptions as values:
out = dict(re.findall(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)*\.) (.*?)\.* ?\d+', txt))

Output:
{'30.1.3.1.': 'Boite à eau',
 '30.1.3.2.': 'Descentes d’eaux pluviales en façades ',
 '30.1.3.3.': 'Lanterneau de désenfumage',
 '30.1.3.4.': 'Etanchéité résine'}


thanks for your help but your regex has got a strange behaviour (but it is better than mine ;)). Sometimes the label is cut, sometimes, a part of the description (please see my updated) is added but not  about the right code X.Y.Z : {'10.': 'Le choix des coloris se portera sur... '...}. Here the 'label' is wrong because the dict value is a part of 40.5.2.2. description. The label should be "10. LOT 01 VRD"

@A.Dumas well, it's always difficult to have a fully generic regex without knowing all corner cases. Glad you found something that worked for you
